# Use a C++ function in Java

Tags: java, c++, function, java-native-interface

I have a C++ project with some .cpp and .h files. One of these .cpp has a function with this signature:
`int** verts(int L, int W, int l, int w)`
I'd like to use this function in a Java project. Yes, I could rewrite it in Java, but it's a very very articulated function. It would be great calling this function (and obtain a matrix of integers) from Java.
Any idea?
Please consider that I'm a Java programmer, I'm very noob in C++ :P

Comment: There are plenty of examples for jni. Here's one http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a library which contains this function, and wraps it with 
a JNI wrapper, but it's not trivial.  The most important question is
what the `int**` really represent, and how they are managed: whether and
how you have to delete them, and how you want to represent them in Java.
Just guessing, I suspect that the pointer points to an array of `int*`,
each of which points to an array of `int`; this is a common
representation for a two dimensional array in C (but not what we'd
normally use in C++).  As for whether and how to delete them, this
should be documented by the library which defines `verts`.  Given that,
you'll first have to declare the function as native in a Java class:

```
class Verts
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary( "<i>libraryName</i>" );
    }

    private static Integer[] nativeVerts( int L, int W, int l, int w );
    public Integer[][] verts( int L, int W, int l, int w )
    {
        Integer[] tmp = nativeVerts( L, W, l, w );
        //  reshape tmp...
        return reshapedData;
    }
}
```

(I've preferred to return a flattened, single dimensional array, rather
than an `Integer[][]`.  It will make the C++ much simpler.)

what you'll have to do is write a function along the following lines:

```
#include "jni.h"
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jIntArray JNICALL Java_Verts_nativeVerts(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jclass,
    jint L,
    jint W,
    jint l,
    jint w)
{
    int** results = verts( L, W, l, w );
    std::vector<int> tmp;
    //  Fill tmp with the flattened results.
    //  Then do whatever you have to do to clean up the int**.
    jintArray jResults = env->newIntArray( tmp.size() );
    env->SetIntArrayRegion( jResults, 0, tmp.size(), &tmp[0] );
    return jResults;
}
```

Except that the above also needs considerably more error checking.

Finally, compile and link the above into a dll with the name you gave to
the `System.loadLibrary()` function on the Java side.  And make sure
your environment is set up so that Java can find the dll (either through
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH (Unix) or %path% (Windows), or by passing the path by
means of `-Djava.library.path=...` on the Java command line).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'd like to try but i get this error when i load the dll... "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"

Comment: i'm on Windows 7 64 bit but i'm using a 32-bit version of jdk

Comment: @Oneiros Then you have to link the DLL as a 32-bit DLL.  (I can't help you there---my Windows machines all run 32-bit versions of Windows.)

Comment: ok i solved that problem... but now i have another one: java can load the dll file but it exit with this error: `A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x10009a7d, pid=2264, tid=3856.` 

This is how i implemented the native method:

`jintArray jResults = env->NewIntArray( tmp.size() );
env->SetIntArrayRegion( jResults, 0, tmp.size(), &tmp[0] );
return (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(n, env->GetObjectClass(jResults), 0);`

Comment: @Oneiros It looks like you've got a bad pointer somewhere, probably in the code which fills `tmp` from the returned `int**`.  But your return statement doesn't make sense either: you don't want to return an `Object[]`, but an `int[]`.  Your return creates a new array of `n` references to `int[]`, all initialized to `null`, and totally ignores the data returned by `verts` and the array you constructed from it.  It's possible to do something like this to construct an `int[][]` to return to Java, but it's more complicated, and doesn't correspond to the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use that function directly (or if you do, you'll have a memory leak, since Java can't know how to free the memory allocated and returned by `verts`).  You should be able to write a simple wrapper that follows the JNI rules though.

When calling across languages, you really need to use caller-provided buffers.  For this function, your wrapper will need to copy the results to the caller-provided buffer, and then use the appropriate C++ function to free the memory returned by `verts`.